# Input to stack data in c

Tags: c, stack, procedure

the purpose of this program is to fill the stack by user input, and show the current value of top stack and number of that "top" variable every after new data input. but looks like my procedure isnt working as i intended. when i run the program "your data" and "current stack size" always 0. did i do smthing wrong ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 5

typedef struct stacktype
{
    double arr[size];
    int top;
} stack;

/*  prototype function */
void push(double elmt,stack c);

/*main program*/
int main(void)
{

char a;
double b;
stack c;

c.top=0;
printf("will you insert a data  (Y/N) ?\n");
scanf("%c",&a);
while (a=='Y'){

    printf("insert your data :\n");
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    push (b,c);
    printf("your data is : %.2f",c.arr[c.top]);
    printf("current stack size : %d",c.top);

    if(c.top!=size){
        printf("will you insert a data (Y/N) ?\n");
        scanf("%s",&a);
    }
}
return 0;
}

/* Implementation */
void push(double elmt, stack c)
{
   if(c.top!=size) {
        c.top = c.top + 1;
        c.arr[c.top] = elmt;
   }
   else {
        printf("Stack is full\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&a);` - since `a` is a single `char`, that isn't going to end well. And if you do manage to fix that, consider 1. what value of `a` *keeps* you in that loop, and 2. whether that value of `a` ever changes once your stack reaches `size`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the parameters to the function 'push()' with their reference like so..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 5

typedef struct stacktype
{
    double arr[size];
    int top;
} stack;

/*  prototype function */
void push(double elmt,stack *p_c);

/*main program*/
int main(void)
{

    char a;
    double b;
    stack c;

    c.top=0;
    printf("will you insert a data  (Y/N) ?\n");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    while (a=='Y'){
        printf("insert your data :\n");
        scanf("%lf",&b);
        push(b,&c); // Address of c
        printf("your data is : %.2f",c.arr[c.top]);
        printf("current stack size : %d",c.top);

        if(c.top!=size){
            printf("will you insert a data(Y/N) ?\n");
            scanf("%s",&a);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Implementation */
void push(double elmt, stack *p_c)
{
    if(p_c->top!=size) {
        p_c->top = p_c->top + 1;
        p_c->arr[p_c->top] = elmt;
    }
    else {
        printf("Stack is full\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but will never end, i feel like my program logic was wrong. the "stack is full" never happen

Comment: i got it finally, changing arr[size] to arr[6]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your stack variable ***C*** by reference to the function push(). Then only, changes made inside the push() function will be reflected to the stack variable c in the main() function.

Also, ***c.top*** should be equal to -1 initially because in the function push(), you are first incrementing top data member of stack variable and then storing the data to the array of stack variable. By this, first element will be stored at 0.

```
/*  prototype function */
void push(double elmt,stack *c);

/*main program*/
int main(void)
{

    char a;
    double b;
    stack c;

    c.top=-1;
    printf("will you insert a data  (Y/N) ?\n");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    while (a=='Y'){

    printf("insert your data :\n");
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    push (b,&c);
    printf("your data is : %.2f",c.arr[c.top]);
    printf("current stack size : %d",c.top);

    if(c.top!=size){
        printf("will you insert a data (Y/N) ?\n");
        scanf("%s",&a);
   }
   }
    return 0;
}

/* Implementation */
void push(double elmt, stack *c)
{
    if(c->top!=size) {
        c->top = c->top + 1;
        c->arr[c->top] = elmt;
    }
    else {
         printf("Stack is full\n");
    }
}
```